# Right way to keep media resources for flash game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

We are developing an epic game using flash cs5 and actionscript 3 (no flex at all).
There are lots of images and other media stuff in library that we need to use. Early i just kept them in my main .fla, but then compiling swf became very slow (more images - more time to compile). So i put all my images to filesystem outside flash, and it helps. But then some lags and bugs appeared, especially when we were testing the game on remote server. Seems like files just don't have time to load (or they loaded uncompletely) - though i did it pretty correct, sequentially, with events like onload and so on.

Finally i've created another swf with all the images and resources. I'm loading it once in my main swf and i compile it only when i need to add a new image. It works rather well, but i have feeling that i'm doing it wrong or there is another right way to organize resources more easy. Also there are some minor troubles with second swf; for example, i have to make user wait until it loads inside my first file, and if i want to run from my desktop, i always must keep these two files near in one place. And, as amount of images growth and growth, it becomes annoying to compile my 2nd swf again, even if i need to do it not so often.

So i'm searching for the acknowledged, common and correct way to organize resources for my game, that is used by game developers, that i could learn and use.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is build an asset manager class (or classes). This class should deal with *all* loading of assets so that you easily can change the way you are loading them without having to make changes all over the place.

The sane way for development is to load the files externally, you can easily replace them and if you're working in a team you won't have to deal with the issue of conflicts on your main .fla file. (That means each file on it's own, not a single asset swf)

You might want to use a loading library for this, since it's not very fun coding, I often use [BulkLoader](https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader). It's a bit on the big side, but it works well.

However, when deploying to a server, depending on the type of your game, it might be a bit of a hassle to get all those files up there. Many flash game sites don't even support multiple files but rather prefer one giant .swf. That's when it's time for your asset loading class to shine, since it's all wrapped by one class you can change the internal workings of it to use .zip files or if you want the single file, the `[Embed]` tag (requires the mxmlc compiler, but it's real easy to set up)

And please, don't ever turn of warnings, it'll cause you way more problems than it solves.

Comment: +1 I fully support this answer. As stated most flash game sites don't allow multiple files. (though the big 3 do) Asset manager class using embedding is what I usually use. If your game is intended to be one file that is the way to go. Again don't turn off warnings hehe. Way too many people are suggesting this more and more.

Comment: Embedding is also very laborious way to organize many images. We are going to have pseudo-3d objects, where 1 object presented by ~25 images with different angle view, and there can be hundreds of objects. About asset manager, fortunately i guess to create and use it from the beginning, so no problems here. I also created a simple class that works like bulkloader but as i wrote in post there were problems with running it on remote server.

Comment: Create and embed them as sprite sheets. Trying to embed tons of individual images would be nuts I agree with you.

Comment: If your loading class isn't working properly, that's not a problem with the concept, it'd say it's just a bug of some kind in your code. Post it as another question and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: As for generating embed tags, check out this blog post: http://www.andymoore.ca/2011/03/embedding-assets-in-as3/

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways flash developers can organize assets for games, but the best method depends on what kind of game you're developing.

Many games use tiles for building their levels, and spritesheets for entities/characters/etc and so its possible to find several frameworks that have this functionality built-in - PushbuttonEngine (http://pushbuttonengine.com/) springs to mind - but I assume you've progressed too far to switch engines at this point.

One strategy you might like to check out is to put each tileset (or group of related assets) inside a zip file and then to load that. There are many good AS3 libraries out there that allow you to parse zip files inside of Flash, but the nochump.com implementation is perhaps one of the best: http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15

That way you can still work in a modular way, and won't have to compile a swf file every time something changes. You'd still need to unzip/zip your assets whenever something changes, but that'll still be a lot quicker than compiling inside of Flash or loading all assets individually at runtime (which could potentially kill your webserver, having to handle 100's of requests for a single game-session).

Also, since you complain about long compilation times in Flash, give this a try: Under Actionscript Settings, uncheck the box labeled "Warnings Mode". Warnings Mode gives you compiler warnings about obvious stuff like untyped variables or duplicate variables, etc... but turning it off can really cut down on your compile time.

I discovered this when I was working on a very asset-heavy project and after disabling it I went from 30 seconds to 5 seconds to compile my swf.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I've thought about frameworks, but it was too late to switch, yep. And i'm sorry about it :) Zip files are good idea, i will try to use that library. Disabling warnings mode is a good thing too, i've done it already.

Comment: Pretty please, don't turn off warnings. That *will* come back and bite you.

Comment: What downsides are there to turning off warnings? I've turned off warnings for years now and never once had a problem with it. Also, if you use a separate IDE like Flex/Flashbuilder or FDT to do your coding and Flash itself as your final compiler, you can get the best of both worlds: warnings in your code-editor, and quick compilation in your assets-editor.